# Inkscape user interface - customise the width of docked toolboxes

Tags: user-interface, inkscape

I recently installed Inkscape 1.3. One annoyance to me is that the width of docked toolbars on the righthand side of the screen always varies, according to which toolbar is opened at the moment. I attach two screenshots to illustrate what I mean:

Narrow docked toolbar:
[image]

Wider docked toolbar:
[image]

There seems to be plenty of space to display the actual content of each toolbar, so I don't understand why Inkscape resizes the second toolbar (the Fill and Stroke toolbar).

I usually open toolbars with shortcuts, therefore this is disrupting to my workflow. Is there any way to fix the width of docked toolsbars and ideally keep them as narrow as possible to have a large working canvas?